# Unity width and height of the gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following gameobject in unty:

[image]

I need to get the width and height of it from a c#

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to do this. If your object has a renderer, you can use `renderer.bounds.size`, which will return a vector with the height and width (and depth, if it is in 3D).

You can also get the width and height from the colliders on a gameObject as well, by using `collider.bounds.size`. Try something like this:

```
public Vector3 size;
private MeshRenderer renderer;

private void Start() {
    renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    size = renderer.bounds.size;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

A `GameObject` doesn't have a width or a height but the information it contains *could*.  In your case, you have a `MeshRenderer` and that conveniently has a [`bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) property which will return an...

> axis-aligned bounding box fully enclosing the object in world space.

If you have a reference to the `MeshRenderer` on that object:

```
MeshRenderer renderer;
```

then getting the bounds is as easy as:

```
renderer.bounds;
```

and then you can observe its [`size`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-size.html) property.

---

Keep in mind this is the world space bounding information so all rotations and scalings will affect it.  If you'd like the raw details of the mesh itself, you'll need a reference to the `MeshFilter`, look at its `mesh` property, and use the [`bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) property on *that* `Mesh` object.

Comment: Does it take transform.scale and transform.localScale into account?

Comment: @KamranBigdely It does.  I've updated my answer to also include information on how to get the bounds details of the raw `Mesh` object itself, which takes no transform details into consideration.